# How do I use numba's "guvectorize" decorator to change two arrays in the same function?

Tags: numba

I'm using numba's @guvectorize to change two different arrays. The code is:

```
@guvectorize([(int64[:], int64[:], int64[:], int64[:])], '(n),(n)->(n),(n)', target= 'parallel')

def g(x, y, res, res_two):
    res = x
    for i in range(x.shape[0]-1):
        var = np.random.poisson((2),1)[0]
        res_two[i] = var
        res[i+1] = res[i] + res_two[i]
    print("res[i+1] is", res[i+1], "for x[i] is", x[i])    

q = (np.arange(5)) * 0
q[0] = 5
r = (np.arange(5)) * 0
   
g(q,r)
print("q is", q)
print("r is", r)
```

And the results printed out are:

[image]

As one can see, q is changing, but r isn't.

What must I do to use guvectorize to input two arrays and change those two arrays?

Comment: There is nothing about your code that has anything to do with CUDA or GPUs.  Please don't add irrelevant tags.

Comment: If I change the target from parallel to cuda doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, then there would be some relevance.  However, since what you are doing obviously is not working for you even with target parallel, the problem is not specific to CUDA.

Comment: Your function doesn't do anything with y at any point